# Why do I get an invalid isoformat string using datetime.fromisoformat()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, time

My timestanp string is as follows

```
mytime = 2021-10-25T14:17:13+0000
```

As you can see the timezone is shown as `0000` instead of `00:00`.
This seems to cause an error when I do

```
newtime = datetime.fromisoformat(mytime)

Invalid isoformat string: '2021-10-25T14:17:13+0000'
```

How should I proceed to convert this string into a datetime object?

Comment: What format is that timestamp and where are you getting it from?

Comment: `datetime.fromisoformat()` is only meant to parse time strings created by `datetime.isoformat()`, which accepts only a subset of ISO-8601 formats. You'll need to use some other method in the linked post.

Comment: yes I checked that post, and when I use `datetime.strptime(mytime), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+%z')` I get `time data '2021-10-25T14:17:13+0000' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+%z'`—any ideas?

Comment: You'll need to remove the plus sign in "+%z" since the plus sign is already part of %z

Comment: worth to mention I think that dateutil's isoparser seems to be more efficient than datetime's strptime (e.g. `parser.isoparse('2021-10-25T14:17:13+0000')` is nearly 2x faster in `%timeit` on my machine.